# Mistyped command: sudo nano / -name "supervisor"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, nano

Instead of using `sudo find / -name "supervisor"` I ran `sudo nano / -name "supervisor"` by mistake, which looked like it opened a blank nano file before I hit `CRTL-X`...

```
$ sudo nano / -name "supervisor"
Use "fg" to return to nano.

[1]+  Stopped                 sudo nano / -name "supervisor"
```

The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone have any idea what it was trying to do? I mainly want to know if I have messed anything up on the server. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command would have started the `nano` editor and instructed it to edit the root directory.  `nano` would have complained with a `[ "/" is a directory ]` message. No files would have been changed.

Comment: Perfect thanks, I'll accept it as soon as I can.